# What is a "$_FILES Corruption Attack"

Tags: php

I came across the following piece of Code for validating uploaded files here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

```
// Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
// If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
if (
    !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
    is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
) {
```

But what is a "$_FILES Corruption Attack"?
(How) does the mentioned Code prevent it?
How would I change it, if I want to enable multiple Files to be uploaded?

Comment: its checking if the $_FILES array has one of the error flags set: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: don't errors just change the int value of $_FILES[ 'upfile' ][ 'error' ][ $i ]? If $_FILES[ 'upfile' ][ 'error' ] is an array it just means multiple files are uploaded (with or without errors) or am I getting that wrong? ( $i beeing the index of an uploaded file )

Comment: agreed, the comment makes very little sense to me

Comment: There is a directory traversal attack that is done through mangling indices in the $_FILES array. It appears to have been fixed in 5.4. See this blog post by Neal Poole for some details. It then links to further info. https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/10/directory-traversal-via-php-multi-file-uploads/